# If you have multiple Applications, is it a good design practice to store users in one table with a column that differentiate the Application

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a C# project called Authentication that allows users to login and get their login credential checked and if passes, returns the token.

I want to reuse that C# Authentication project for other Applications that I am designing. Is it a good practice to store all the users from different Applications in one table or is there a better way to go about coding for One Authentication project for many Applications?

Comment: You don't have to reuse the database when you are reusing code. each application can have its own database with the Users table. Unless you want some kind of centralized solution?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

There is a difference between code reuse and infrastructure reuse. The former is OK as you get a clean separation between the applications. Sharing a database is not recommended as it can introduce security vulnerabilities if you do not design it carefully.

I would also separate the notion of users and accounts. An account is used to log into an application and load the correct permissions. i.e. the account controls what an user can do in an application while the "user" object describes the user itself.

If you separate it like that, it's much easier to create a reusable library as everything related to authentication/authorization is in its own part. That's because the authentication design rarely changes. What differs in applications is typically the information that describes the user and the kind of customization that every user want to have.

Short answer:

- Separate everything related to authentication and authorization into an "Account" object.
- Collect everything describing the user into an "User" object.
- Reuse the account part, but build the "user" part in every application.

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever share the database between services. It will create a maintenance nightmare.
Every DB should be designed around (and after) the Bounded Context handled by the relative microservice.

In your case this means one DB to store the authentication data, then another DB per-service, with the relative data.

It is perfectly fine to have a `Users` table in separate DBs holding some duplicate data. As long as you're diligent enough and have a good strategy for keeping that data in sync.